# jquery validate, add, delete email address

Tags: jquery, validation, email-validation, qtip

I am trying to validate an email address and then add to a multi select box. I am using qTip and jquery validate to do the trick. So when hit Add button, the script should validate and add to the select box below. Validating is working fine, but for adding am facing little difficulty adding the method to main qTip script. Can anyone help me in integrating the below

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pixelfx/u38Q5/)

Add Script

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#addButton").click(function() {
    var arr = new Array();
    $('#emailRecipients option').each(function(){
        arr.push($(this).attr('value'))
    });
    var duplicateFlag = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i].toString() == $('#validate').val()) {
            duplicateFlag = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(duplicateFlag) {
        alert('sorry...');
    } else {
        $('#emailRecipients').append($("<option>" + $('#validate').val() + "</option>"));
    }
    return false;
});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're validating by string comparison you can tighten up your code below. Also, you'll want to change the jquery you have in your .append() method to be raw HTML and add the email address to the options value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#addButton").click(function(){
        var emails = [];
        $("#emailRecipients option").each(function(){
            emails.push($(this).val());
        });

        if( $.inArray($('#validate').val(), emails) != -1 ){
            alert("sorry...");
        }else{
            $('#emailRecipients').append("<option value='" + $('#validate').val() + "'>" + $('#validate').val() + "</option>");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I am trying to add this logic qTip Script where iam validating and showing the error message onMouseover.  Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pixelfx/u38Q5/)

Comment: @Ravi: you may have less trouble doing it the other way around. That is, instead of incorporating logic to a component, such as adding the code above to .validate(), you should validate() and create a qTip for the textfield if they enter an email address that has already been entered. (e.g. instead of alerting "sorry..." create the qTip for the textfield letting them know they've already entered the email address)